# Mockery, App Instance not working on some laravel tests

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit, mockery

Basically, my question is; Why does the `$this->app->instance()` Call work on one instance of the mocked object, but the other doesn't...

In the example below, the **getGroupSingleSignOnLink** function actually gets called, the other is mocked and the test passes...

## TEST

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\Group;
use App\Models\User;
use Tests\TestCase;
use App\Clients\SingleSignOnApi;
use Mockery;

class SingleSignOnTest extends TestCase
{

    private $validUrl = 'http://www.google.com';

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $single_sign_on = Mockery::mock(SingleSignOnApi::class);

        $single_sign_on->shouldReceive('getGroupSingleSignOnLink')->andReturn($this->validUrl);
        $single_sign_on->shouldReceive('getSingleSignOnLink')->andReturn($this->validUrl);

        $this->app->instance(SingleSignOnApi::class, $single_sign_on);
    }

    //THIS TEST FAILS, SingleSignOnApi Class Not Mocked
    public function testGroupAuthConnection()
    {
        $group = Group::whereNotNull('external_platform_key')->first();
        $user = $group->users()->first();

        $this->be($user);

        $group_sso = $group->groupAuthConnections()->first();
        $response = $this->get(route('sso.group.connect', ['id' => $group_sso->id]));

        $response->assertRedirect($this->validUrl);
        $response->assertSessionMissing('__danger');
    }

    //THIS TEST PASSES, The SingleSignOnApi Class is Mocked
    public function testAuthConnectionConnect()
    {
        $user = User::first();
        $this->be($user);

        $sso = $user->authConnections()->firstOrFail();
        $response = $this->get(route('sso.connect', ['id' => $sso->id]));

        $response->assertRedirect($this->validUrl);
        $response->assertSessionMissing('__danger');
    }

}
```

## CONTROLLER FUNC - TEST MOCK WORKING

```
public function connect($id)
{
    $auth_connection = $this->findAuthConnection($id, Auth::user());

    $sso_client = App::make(SingleSignOnApi::class);
    $url        = $sso_client->getSingleSignOnLink($auth_connection);

    return redirect($url);
}
```

## CONTROLLER FUNC - TEST MOCK NOT WORKING

```
public function connect($id)
{
    $group_ids = Auth::user()->groups()->pluck('groups.id')->toArray();

    $group_auth_connection = $this->findGroupAuthConnection($id, Auth::user());

    //This is the Mocked Object in my Test: SingleSignOnApi
    $sso_client = App::make(SingleSignOnApi::class, [$group_auth_connection->group->external_platform_key]);
    $url = $sso_client->getGroupSingleSignOnLink($group_auth_connection, Auth::user());

    return redirect($url);
}
```

Comment: What output makes you believe that the problem is with `instance`?

Comment: The output... I know because the class isn't mocked in the failing test, it makes the external call... But the other test, same class is getting mocked just fine.

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working? I'm trying to mock some external API calls using this same method and it's just not working.

Comment: No, Sorry @daraul... We never could figure out what's going on.

Comment: @dankuck - I'm making an assumption on instance. Basically, App::make() is still instantiating the Target Class (ie - not using the mocked instance).

Comment: I was actually able to get this working consistently with a few changes. Basically, I instantiate the third party SDK I'm using in the AppServiceProvider. Then in my tests I build a mock version of that, with fake responses, and pass that to `$this->app->instance()`.
I'll do a longer post as an Answer when I get a few more minutes

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I believe it has to do with the params array in the App::make() call, but I'm not sure why exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use Quickbooks as an example to illustrate how I got this to work consistently for me.

Here's my AppServiceProvider, defining a custom QuickbooksSDK Class I created:

```
...
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->bind(QuickbooksSDK::class, function($app) {
            return new QuickbooksSDK(
                new GuzzleHttp\Client([
                    'base_uri' => config('invoicing.baseUri'),
                    'timeout' => 3,
                    'headers' => [
                        'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.config('invoicing.apiKey'),
                        'Accept' => 'application/json'
                    ],
                    'http_errors' => false
                ]),
                config('invoicing.apiKey'),
                env('QUICKBOOKS_REFRESH_TOKEN'),
                env('QUICKBOOKS_CLIENT_ID'),
                env('QUICKBOOKS_CLIENT_SECRET')
            );
        });
    }
```

Then I created a second custom class, called the QuickbooksInvoicingDriver, that takes the instantiated SDK Class from the Service container:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->api = app(QuickbooksSDK::class);
}
```

Finally, in my test class, I can mock the QuickbooksSDK, with my own custom responses, to make testing easier:

```
    $vendorResponse = '{"Vendor": {"Balance": 0,"Vendor1099": false,"CurrencyRef": {"value": "GYD","name": "Guyana Dollar"},"domain": "QBO","sparse": false,"Id": "25","SyncToken": "0","MetaData": {"CreateTime": "2018-04-04T12:36:47-07:00","LastUpdatedTime": "2018-04-04T12:36:47-07:00"},"DisplayName": "daraul","PrintOnCheckName": "daraul","Active": true},"time": "2018-04-04T12:36:47.576-07:00"}';

    $mock = new MockHandler([
        new Response(200, [], $vendorResponse),
    ]);

    $handler = HandlerStack::create($mock);
    $client = new Client(['handler' => $handler]);
    $api = new QuickbooksSDK(
        $client,
        'test',
        'test',
        'test',
        'test'
    );

    $this->app->instance(QuickbooksSDK::class, $api);
```

Now I can run my tests normally, without worrying about third parties. These links were really helpful for me:

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/testing.html

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Sorry for such the long delay. But if I'm reading this correctly, when I attempt to Mock the class, Mockery isn't Mocking every instance of SingleSignOnApi, and thats why I should use a service provider to ensure that the same instance is always returned in my tests/classes/etc... 

I don't have access to the example code base anymore, but I will definitely use this the next time I write some unit tests like above. I'll come back and accept the answer if it works for me, thanks a lot, and sorry (again) for the delay... 

--Cheers

Comment: That's fine. I've since changed how I implement my quickbooks tests, but I figure the answer might still be relevant to the question given when it was asked.